# No module named 'alpaca'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, trading, alpaca

I've been trying to run my code on a Google Colab Workspace that imports various modules from the alpaca-trade-api package. However, I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError, which indicates that the package is not installed in my Python environment.

```
from alpaca.data.historical import CryptoHistoricalDataClient
from alpaca.data.requests import CryptoBarsRequest
from alpaca.data.timeframe import TimeFrame
import datetime as datetime
from alpaca.data.live import StockDataStream
from alpaca.trading.client import TradingClient
from alpaca.trading.requests import MarketOrderRequest
from alpaca.trading.enums import OrderSide, TimeInForce
from alpaca.trading.requests import LimitOrderRequest
```

These are the libraries I have tried to import but i am getting this error.

```
No module named 'alpaca'
```

I have tried both:

```
pip install alpaca

pip install alpaca-trade-api
```

However this does not seem to fix the issue. Any help would be Appreciated :)

Comment: try pip list | grep alpaca. If it's installed you can also try pip show alpaca and get the location of the install.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman it came back with this.                                                         
alpaca                        1.0.0
alpaca-trade-api              3.0.0

Comment: Ok, what is the install path? Another option, and preferred, is to use a virtual environment for each project.

Comment: @AlexHalliday Have you ever successfully installed modules on this setup before?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I am currently using a Google Colab workspace if that makes a difference?

Comment: ha, yes. I would definitely add that detail to your question.

Comment: @KovyJacob This is the first time

Comment: @AlexHalliday you can use pip show alpaca-trade-api to see the path it is installed in.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman sorry, i have now changed it. do you think restarting the workspace or kernel would work?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install alpaca-py` is needed:

```
!pip install alpaca-py
from alpaca.data.historical import CryptoHistoricalDataClient
from alpaca.data.requests import CryptoBarsRequest
from alpaca.data.timeframe import TimeFrame
import datetime as datetime
from alpaca.data.live import StockDataStream
from alpaca.trading.client import TradingClient
from alpaca.trading.requests import MarketOrderRequest
from alpaca.trading.enums import OrderSide, TimeInForce
from alpaca.trading.requests import LimitOrderRequest
```